# C# project build errors after importing button image on toolstrip button

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripbutton

I am just starting to use the `ToolStrip` object on my windows `Form`.

I followed a nice tutorial that explained how to add the tool strip, then add a button, then assign a image to the button.

So, I added the toolstrip and then added the button:

[image: Add button to toolstrip]

As you can see, in the above screen shot I have also tried importing the image. I did this by right-clicking the button and choosing **Set Image**:

[image: Import button]

When I clicked OK, these extra files (**MyGenioViewer1.Designer.cs**) were automatically generated:

[image: Extra files created]

But now the project will not compile. If I restore my previous backup and do everything **except** importing a button, it compiles.

These are the errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0111  Type 'MyGenioView' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types    GENIO Viewer    D:\My Programs\GENIO Viewer\GENIO Viewer\MyGenioView.cs 65  Active
Error   CS0262  Partial declarations of 'MyGenioView' have conflicting accessibility modifiers  GENIO Viewer    D:\My Programs\GENIO Viewer\GENIO Viewer\MyGenioView.Designer.cs    25  Active
Error   CS0260  Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MyGenioView'; another partial declaration of this type exists  GENIO Viewer    D:\My Programs\GENIO Viewer\GENIO Viewer\MyGenioView1.Designer.cs   25  Active
Error   CS0111  Type 'MyGenioView' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types    GENIO Viewer    D:\My Programs\GENIO Viewer\GENIO Viewer\MyGenioView1.Designer.cs   32  Active
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MyGenioView.MyGenioView()' and 'MyGenioView.MyGenioView()'  GENIO Viewer    D:\My Programs\GENIO Viewer\GENIO Viewer\GENIO_Viewer_Form.cs   53  Active
```

Clearly, the addition of these extra files has caused me a problem. I don't know why they were added. I don't know how to resolve the issue. And I don't know how to prevent it.

Thank you for any clarification about resolving this issue correctly.

The original **MyGenioView.Designer.cs** contains:

```
namespace GENIO_Viewer
{
  partial class MyGenioView
  {
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
        components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.SuspendLayout();
      // 
      // MyGenioView
      // 
      this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
      this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
      this.Name = "MyGenioView";
      this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

The new **MyGenioView1.Designer.cs** causing issues is:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace GENIO_Viewer {
    using System;


    /// <summary>
    ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
    /// </summary>
    // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
    // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
    // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
    // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    internal class MyGenioView {

        private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

        private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
        internal MyGenioView() {
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("GENIO_Viewer.MyGenioView", typeof(MyGenioView).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
        ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
            get {
                return resourceCulture;
            }
            set {
                resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a real mess here.  Somehow, you wound up with a Designer file separate from a Form.  One that, in fact, doesn't look like a designer file at all.  What I didn't see in your screenshot was the form to which those Designers are supposed to be linked.

It should look like this:

[image]

You didn't show this class's code:  `MyGenioView.cs`, but I'm guessing it already defines at least some of what is in `MyGenioView1.Designer.cs`.

The bottom line is that you have too many conflicting (partial) classes in too many places.  It looks to me like you should have one class (code page) for `MyGenioView`, and another for the form.  Anything else is conflicting.

P.S. I also wonder if you are confusing WPF constructs with WinForms.  They are vastly different.  Your use of the word 'View' suggested this to me.  I may be wrong.

Comment: I only have one actual form. But what you said got me to think about where a part of my project had come from. So, I removed the redundant **resx/designer** files and then in the original cs removed the `InitializeComponent` call (since there is no form anyway) and voila! :)

Comment: I am using WinForms. I have never used WPF. I simply use the term View because of my MFC background. I renamed my derived UserControl object as a view. That was all. WPF is unknown territory. :)